# When creating a superuser it puts email in username and the opposite way

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a superuser with email and username. I'd like it to be the way that email has the first priority over a username.

I decided to change the built-in user. And so I created 2 classes.  The first is `UserManager(BaseUserManager)`, and the second class is `User(AbstractBaseUser)`

Back to the problem, when I create a superuser through the command line, it creates a user, but it puts an email in the username field and the opposite way with the username.

Here is my models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):

        user_obj = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password):
        ...

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            username,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user



    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        email = models.EmailField(
                verbose_name = 'email address',
                max_length=255,
                unique=True
                )
        username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name='username')
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        USERNAME_FIELD= 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]

        objects = UserManager()
```

Why does it mess up with username and email???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you did, in your `UserManager`, you define:

```
def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
    # ...
```

But later in your code you call this function with:

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        username,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True
    )
    return user
```

So here you call the `create_user` method, but you swapped the `username` and `email` parameters. So you will need to swap the arguments in the call to the `create_user`.

Comment: Man, i love you, you're the best.